# Trigger postpublish script when publish fails

Tags: node.js

I have a postpublish script:

```
"postpublish": "gulp cleanup"
```

however I realized that when the npm publish fails, it doesn't run the postpublish.

Is there any way to force nodejs to run it no matters (like a finally)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There [doesn't seem to be a cleanup npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) script, but you can do something like:

```
"publish": "yourPublishCommand || gulp cleanup"
```

and that `gulp cleanup` will only run when [`yourPublishCommand` returned an error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190546/114692), so you'll have to keep it in the `postpublish` script too.

Answer (score 0):

```
"publish": "(yourPublishCommand && gulp cleanup) || gulp cleanup"
```